# ¿cuál es la mejor solución para poder instalar las librerias composer sin tener NoSslexception y a la vez no tener problemas de inseguridad?

Tags: php, composer

voy a hacer `composer.phar install` para las librerías **diactoros** e **inflector**.

Y me aparece lo siguente:

> [Composer\Exception\NoSslException] The openssl extension is required
>   for SSL/TLS protection but is not  available. If you can not enable
>   the openssl extension, you can disable  this error, at your own risk,
>   by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.

Las soluciones que se plantean causan vulnerabilidad.

¿como puedo solucionar el problema sin causar vulnerabilidad?